# Is there a "see all sheets" keyboard shortcut in Excel 2013 on Windows?

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-excel-2013

When I right-click the arrow buttons on the bottom left corner of Excel, a window listing all sheets will be displayed (as shown below):

[[image: See all sheets option]]

I couldn't find any keyboard shortcut to display this, neither could I declare a new shortcut linked with this window. Is there any shortcut for this option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe there is a direct shortcut for that dialog.

You can get similar by using a small bit of VBA in a macro, and then assigning it to a keyboard shortcut of your choice.

```
Sub ShowAllSheets()
  Application.CommandBars("Workbook tabs").ShowPopup
End Sub
```

- [Source](https://web.archive.org/web/20180818222151/http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/index.php/easily-navigate-many-worksheets/)
- [More Info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff860339.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the correct answer by Techie, here’s a solution that works when you have >15 sheets (and also makes it possible to click a letter to highlight sheet starting with that letter):

```
Sub Select_Sheet()
If ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count <= 16 Then
Application.CommandBars("Workbook Tabs").ShowPopup 500, 225
Else
Application.CommandBars("Workbook Tabs").Controls("More Sheets...").Execute
End If
End Sub
```

Although for unknown reason it does not work when activating using keyboard (as mentioned in [Source](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/5268-macro-choose-worksheet-view-all-wor-3.html) and another example that also dsnt work when using shortcut is [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-to-access-the-sheets-navigation-dialog-box/e8308dd0-d243-49c5-8af2-eb07dba1edee?auth=1)). If someone knows how to fix the code above to work with macro please feel free to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to reply to Stenemo but this is a new account and I need 50 reputation or something.

Anyway, this works:

```
Sub Sheet_Index()

If Application.CommandBars("workbook tabs").Controls(16).Caption Like "More Sheets*" Then
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    If WINDOWS_VER > 5 Then
        If Application.Version = "12.0" Then
            Application.SendKeys "{end}~"""
            Application.CommandBars("workbook tabs").ShowPopup
        Else
            Application.SendKeys "{end}~"
            Application.CommandBars("workbook tabs").Controls(16).Execute
        End If
    Else
        Application.SendKeys "{end}~"
        Application.CommandBars("workbook tabs").ShowPopup
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Else
    Application.CommandBars("workbook tabs").ShowPopup
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Source: https://www.reddit.com/r/excel/comments/383b3z/keyboard_shortcut_for_listing_all_the_worksheet/crs7pah/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x

Cheers.

Edit for some reason if I use this with a keyboard shortcut it turns on and off my num lock every time it's run.